# Como volver a cero un scroll

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

tengo un componente livewire con un formulario de carga de datos muy grande, que cuando lo vuelvo a utilizar, estando en la misma página, el mismo aparece sin problema pero me deja el scroll hacia abajo, donde están los botones para grabar los datos. A continuación, les muestro el código que tengo, y que no funciona, para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Este el el html de mi componente livewire:

```
 <div>
    <button wire:click="ModalNuevaPlanilla()" class="mr-2 inline-flex items-center px-4 py-2 bg-gray-800 border border-transparent rounded-md font-semibold text-xs text-white uppercase tracking-widest hover:bg-gray-700 active:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-900 focus:ring focus:ring-gray-300 disabled:opacity-25 transition">NUEVA PLANILLA</button>

    <section class="modal" x-cloak x-show="AltaNuevaPlanilla = $wire.AltaNuevaPlanilla" x-transition.duration.700ms>
        <div class="modal__container1" id="modal__container1">

            <span class="titListas margenInf15">DATOS DE LA DESCRIPCIÓN DE LA CAUSA</span>

            <div class="Tab-38">
                <div class="Tab-38-c1 formato-celdas padding-10px">
                    <span>Fecha</span>
                    <input id="fecCausa" wire:model="fecCausa" class="camposDeFechas" type="date">
                    @error('fecCausa')
                        <span class="margenIzq-10 msgError1">{{$message}}</span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="Tab-38-c2 formato-celdas padding-10px">
                    <span>Provincia</span>
                    <select wire:model="idProvincia" class="form-select combosDespleg1">
                        <option value="">Seleccionar...</option>
                        @foreach ( $tbAux_1 as $it )
                            <option value="{{$it->item_vari}}">{{$it->desc_vari}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
...
```

y este otro fragmento es el código en javascrip con el que intento volver a cero el scroll

```
    @section('fuentes_js')
        <script>
    
            Livewire.on('VerFormulario', varCampo => {
                var miDiv = document.getElementById('modal__container1');
                miDiv.scrollTop = 0;
            })

...
```

Cada vez que se muestra este formulario, lo hago mediante una función en el código del componente que conmuta una variable para mostrar el componente en un modal. Esta función es la que dispara el evento que estoy atrapando en el segundo fragmento de código, la muestro aqui:

```
public function ModalNuevaPlanilla(){
    $this->AltaNuevaPlanilla=true;
    $this->emit('VerFormulario', 'fecCausa');
}
```

He probado mediante un console.log('paso aqui') que estoy ingresando a la función VerFormulario(), pero lo que no está funcionando es miDiv.scrollTop = 0; para que el formulario se muestre desde arriba y no que aparezca desplazado hacia abajo.

A continuación, les muestro un par de imágenes para que vean mejor el comportamiento que está teniendo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el formulario que aparece:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image]

Ahora bien, si vuelvo a presionar el botón para iniciar otro proceso de carga, el formulario aparecerá con el scroll hacia abajo y lo que quiero hacer es que aparezca arriba, como se ve en la segunda img.

Gracias y saludos

Comment: Se me ocurren 2 cosas: (1) tienes el id repetido en algún otro lado o (2) El scroll lo hace en el `section` que está arriba de `modal__container1`

Comment: He revisado ambos puntos y en el primer caso, no estoy repitiendo el id, en la segunda sugerencia, el scroll está sobre el modal interno. Seguiré revisando opciones. Gracias y Saludos.